# Understanding Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I'm given a prompt to determine the Probability of a single event.

Known:

P(A | B) = .7

P(A | ~B) = .3

P(B | A) = .6

**I need to figure out P(A).**

P(A|B) = (P(B | A)*P(A)) / ((P(B | A)*P(A)) + P(B | ~A)*P(~A))

I am a bit lost on how to derive P(B | ~A) and P(~A) from the given known elements.

I don't think P(B | ~A) = (1 - P(B | A)) but even if it is, how do I get P(~A)?

Answer (score 1):

$P(A \cap B)=0.7 P(B)$ and $P(A \cap B)=0.6 P(A)$  from the first and the last equations. Let $P(A)=c$. Then we get $P(B)=\frac {0.6}{0.7}c$. Now $P(A\cap \sim B)=0.3 P(\sim B)=0.3 (1-P(B))=0.3 (1-\frac {0.6}{0.7}c)$ from the second equation. Also $P(A \cap B)=0.6 P(A)$. Add these two equations. You get $c=P(A)=P(A\cap \sim B)+P(A \cap B)=0.3 (1-\frac {0.6}{0.7}c)+0.6 c$. Now solve this equation for $c$.

Comment: tyvm. Can you explain your third step? "Add these two equations." Why are you adding the two equations? In order to isolate P(A) wouldnt you want to do:
P(A) = P(A∩B) - P(B∩~A)

Comment: $A$ is the disjoint union of $A \cap B$ and $A \cap \sim B$. So adding the probabilities of these events gives you $P(A)$. @snicksnackpaddywhack91

Comment: again thank you so much. But reading the prompt again, I think I may have misunderstood the question and posted the wrong question. I believe I am looking for P(B). Would it be as simple as finding P(A) and taking the compliment of it? P(B) = 1 - P(A)?

Comment: @snicksnackpaddywhack91 I have already shown that $P(B)=\frac {0.6} {0.7} P(A)$.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting tripped up on is (A ∩∼B) and then how to solve for P(B): https://imgur.com/a/wEQ3AGM
I feel like I'm going in circles.

Comment: So would P(B) = P(A∩B)  + P(~A∩B)
A∩B  is known from equations above,
But where does P(~A∩B) get derived?

Comment: @snicksnackpaddywhack91 In the absence of independence we cannot write $P( A\cap B)$ and $P(A \sim B)$ in terms of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. So our strategy should be to get rid of these two probabilities (by adding them).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm completely lost at this point. Thank so much for your help and consideration ad I'm sorry I wasn't able to grasp the concept from you

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be helpful to consider what I regard as the classic conditional probability problem.  I offer this problem only as a way of kick-starting the OP's intuition around conditional probability problems.

You are given two weather forecasters : Mr. R and Mr. S.

You are **given** that Mr. R's forecasts are accurate $80\%$ of the time.

You are **given** that Mr. S's forecasts are accurate $90\%$ of the time.

One morning, Mr. R says it will rain, and Mr. S says it will not rain

What are the chances of rain?

---

It is important to realize that the problem **can not** be solved without making the following assumptions.

Normally, the forecasts of Mr. R and Mr. S are considered **independent** events.

Let A denote the event that Mr. R is right and Mr. S is right.
Let B denote the event that Mr. R is right and Mr. S is wrong.
Let C denote the event that Mr. R is wrong and Mr. S is right.
Let D denote the event that Mr. R is wrong and Mr. S is wrong.

$p(A) = 0.8 \times 0.9 = 0.72.$ 
$p(B) = 0.8 \times 0.1 = 0.08.$ 
$p(C) = 0.2 \times 0.9 = 0.18.$ 
$p(D) = 0.2 \times 0.1 = 0.02.$

The problem is (in effect) asking:
Given that either events B or C occurred,
what is the chance that event B occurred.

Answer:
$\frac{p(B)}{p(B) + p(C)} = \frac{.08}{.08 + .18}.$

More formally, in Bayes Theorem *parlance*:
Let E denote the event that Mr. R and Mr. S disagree.
Then you want $p(B|E)$.

Here, you use the formula that 
$p(E) \times p(B|E) = p(B ~\text{and} ~E ~\text{both occur}) = p(B).$ 
Thus, $p(B|E) = \frac{p(B)}{p(E)} = \frac{.08}{.08 + .18}.$

Answer (score 0):

This can be also visually solved using the basic Venn-Diagram. Let the orange circle represent the set of event A and the green circle represents the set of event B. x is the number of events favourable to only A, y is the number of events favourable both A and B, number of events favourable to only B and w is the number of events not favourable to A or B.

[image]

$$P\left(A|B\right)=\frac{y}{y+z}=\frac{7}{10}$$
$$\implies z=\frac{3y}{7}$$

Also,
$$P(B|A)=\frac{y}{x+y}=\frac{6}{10}$$
$$\implies x=\frac{2y}{3}$$

Similarly,
$$P(A|~B)=\frac{x}{x+w}=\frac{3}{10}$$
$$\implies w=\frac{7x}{3}=\frac{14y}{9}$$

Now, we need to calculate
$$P(A)=\frac{\left(x+y\right)}{x+y+z+w}$$

Just substitute the values and you have the answer.

---

If there are only 2 sets of events mentioned in the question, this is the easiest way to solve such problems. However, visualizing 3 or more sets of events may be difficult and require considerable practice. So, I would recommend you to stick to the algebraic method, meanwhile having an idea of the Venn-Diagram in the back of your mind if you get stuck.

Comment: I just saw your comment of finding P(B)... Well... it is evidently (y+z)/(x+y+z+w)... Also P(A ∩∼B) is (x)/(x+y+z+w)