# How to prove that $P(A) + P\left( {\bar A} \right)P\left( {B|\bar A} \right) = 1 - P\left( {\bar A \cap \bar B} \right)$?

Tags: probability

How to show that without using Venn Diagram

$P(A) + P\left( {\bar A} \right)P\left( {B|\bar A} \right) = 1 - P\left( {\bar A \cap \bar B} \right)$ ?

Effort so far

$P(A) + P\left( {\bar A} \right)P\left( {B|\bar A} \right) = P(A) + P\left( {B,\bar A} \right)$

I have a feeling it has something to do with Boolean Logic Absorption's Law (   X + Y Z = (X + Y) • (X + Z)) but I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(A) + P(\overline{A}) P(B\mid \overline{A})$$$$ = P(A) + P(\overline{A}) \frac{P(B\cap \overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}$$
$$= P(A) + P(B \cap \overline{A}) $$
$$=P(A \cup (B \cap \overline{A}))$$
$$= P(A \cup B)$$
$$=1 - P(\overline{A\cup B})$$
$$= 1 - P(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})$$

Comment: Is this still true if $A$ and $B$ are not independent ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh Of course, my proof does not use that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

As $$P(B|\overline{A}) = \frac{P(B \cap \overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}$$
the second term in your sum simplifies to $P(B \cap \overline{A})$ and $$A \cup (B \cap \overline{A}) \cup (\overline{B} \cap \overline{A})$$

is a partition of $U$.

Answer (score 1):

A visualization for your problem:

Before that, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3825482/823370)

[image]

$$P\left(A\right)+P\left(\bar A\right)P\left(B|\bar A\right)$$
$$=\frac{x+y}{x+y+z+w}+\left(\frac{z+w}{x+y+z+w}\right)\left(\frac{z}{z+w}\right)$$
$$=\frac{x+y+z}{x+y+z+w}$$
$$=1-\frac{w}{x+y+z+w}$$
$$=1-P(\bar A\cap\bar B)$$

Note that the method of Venn-Diagrams is extremely helpful in cases of 2 sets. But I don't suggest it for more than 3 sets.

Comment: I agree with you, I should stick to algebraic manipulation when the number of variable is large. Also your visualization technique is nice, what kind of software do you use to create these diagrams ?

Comment: Just geogebra.... You may see my other answers as well... I always try to put visual and intuitive interpretations of various problems which people don't tend to think in that way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** After a little manipulation , it is equivalent to

Sum of probability of "A" , "A but not B" and "neither A nor B" = 1 , use a Venn diagram and imagination from here onwards.